Unity failed Login with Google Play Games
I have been using the following guide to set up Google play games services in my new android game here
However I keep getting the same error whether I try on mobile or in unity:
Exception: Failed
GPmanager.Start () (at Assets/Scripts/menu/GPmanager.cs:25)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore+<>c.<ThrowAsync>b__7_0 (System.Object state) (at <bfbc89a04b6b4dd49c3614d03fc31ce8>:0)
UnityEngine.UnitySynchronizationContext+WorkRequest.Invoke () (at <f7237cf7abef49bfbb552d7eb076e422>:0)
UnityEngine.UnitySynchronizationContext.Exec () (at <f7237cf7abef49bfbb552d7eb076e422>:0)
UnityEngine.UnitySynchronizationContext.ExecuteTasks () (at <f7237cf7abef49bfbb552d7eb076e422>:0)

and my GPManager Script (shown below) outputs this error: Failed to retrieve Google play games authorization code
GPManager (As seeeen in tutorial):
    public string Token;
    public string Error;

    void Awake()
    {
        PlayGamesPlatform.Activate();
    }

    async void Start()
    {
        await UnityServices.InitializeAsync();
        await LoginGooglePlayGames();
        await SignInWithGooglePlayGamesAsync(Token);
    }
    //Fetch the Token / Auth code
    public Task LoginGooglePlayGames()
    {
        var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<object>();
        PlayGamesPlatform.Instance.Authenticate((success) =>
        {
            if (success == SignInStatus.Success)
            {
                Debug.Log("Login with Google Play games successful.");
                PlayGamesPlatform.Instance.RequestServerSideAccess(true, code =>
                {
                    Debug.Log("Authorization code: " + code);
                    Token = code;
                    // This token serves as an example to be used for SignInWithGooglePlayGames
                    tcs.SetResult(null);
                });
            }
            else
            {
                Error = "Failed to retrieve Google play games authorization code";
                Debug.Log("Login Unsuccessful");
                tcs.SetException(new Exception("Failed"));
            }
        });
        return tcs.Task;
    }


    async Task SignInWithGooglePlayGamesAsync(string authCode)
    {
        try
        {
            await AuthenticationService.Instance.SignInWithGooglePlayGamesAsync(authCode);
            Debug.Log($"PlayerID: {AuthenticationService.Instance.PlayerId}"); //Display the Unity Authentication PlayerID
            Debug.Log("SignIn is successful.");
        }
        catch (AuthenticationException ex)
        {
            // Compare error code to AuthenticationErrorCodes
            // Notify the player with the proper error message
            Debug.LogException(ex);
        }
        catch (RequestFailedException ex)
        {
            // Compare error code to CommonErrorCodes
            // Notify the player with the proper error message
            Debug.LogException(ex);
        }
    }

I have tried completely reconfiguring my my OAuth consents, testing on android devices and emulators, adding all accounts on the devices to the tester lists, installing from a internal test of google play (Using there SHA1 keys) and from the .apk builds from unity (Using my SHA1 keys from keystore) all to no avail.
Any ideas?
Unity - 2022.3.18f1
GPS plugin - v11.01
Unity Auth - 3.3.1
